# Backup MySQL databases from broken Ubuntu

Tags: backup, mysql

Here is my problem, and I hope someone would help me to find a solution. My Ubuntu 12.04 is broken after an upgrade from 11.10, it won't boot up, just stops at the purple Ubuntu screen, but I can still acces partition via Live USB. Now I want to go back to the old 11.10 with an complete reinstall, but I have to backup some of my MySQL databases from my broken system, is there an easy way to do this? The help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do a copy of your databases located in here.`var/lib/mysql`

The in the fresh install of your mysql stop the mysql. `service mysql stop`
change the */var/lib/mysql* with your data, then re-run the mysql `service mysql start`

Comment: That should work--any subtle storage engine changes would be harmful though

Comment: I'm guessing this method requires the old and the new install of MySQL server to have the same exact version? Correct?

Comment: It could work on diferent versions but I'm not so sure about it.